# Batch command not recognized when executed through python

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, python

I tried running a batch command (`ssh ...`) through Python's `os.system()` function. It should be noted that the said command is recognized when I run it directly from `cmd`; however, the same fails through the Python `subprocess` call.

In `cmd`:
[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import os
os.system("ssh ...")
```

In Python:
[image]

Running a .py file:
[image]

Why is the `ssh` command (which ***is*** a recognized executable) not recognized when run through Python's subprocess call?

Comment: python may need full path to `ssh`

Comment: @furas Well, this thing works for other commands (like `node`) when done the same way as shown in the post. And the path of `ssh` is (obviously) supplied in the Environment Variable value

Comment: `ssh` is not batch command but normal program `c:\....\ssh.exe`. System use variable `PATH` with list of folders in which it should search this program.

Comment: When you installed `ssh`, did you install it only for yourself, or for all users of the system?

Comment: you can compare `PATH` in system and `os.getenv('PATH')` in Python. Maybe there is difference

Comment: @JohnGordon I installed for all users

Comment: Then it should be in the systemwide `PATH`, so I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah; however I think @furas's comment has a point. I basically setup `ssh` on my computer by Installing `Putty`. And the System PATH has a link to the directory of Putty, which **does not contain ssh.exe**. I am gonna try to reference the PATH of an `ssh.exe` file (that comes bundled with **Git**) which I think will work. I think the `ssh` functionality is currently somewhow being routed through Putty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh` is not a standard windows executable (***yet!***), it would have been installed from a 3rd party.

So you probably don't have the path to `ssh` in the environmental path variable.

Either:

- Try executing with full path in Python

*or*:

- Open up a `cmd` prompt and add it using this method (replace `YOUR_PATH` with your path to the directory where `ssh.exe` exists).

  ```
  PATH YOUR_PATH;%Path%
  ```

  e.g.

  ```
  PATH C:\Program Files\Some_SSH\bin\;%Path%
  ```

This will permanently add it to the path on the system.

Comment: Executing `PATH C:\Program Files\Some_SSH\bin\;%Path%` from a command line prompt will _not_ permanently add it to the system. To do that on Windows you need to modify a System setting through a control panel. The details of doing that vary slightly on the different versions of the OS and may require administrative privileges.

Comment: @martineau, thankfully modifying the variable in the shell isn't permament. Before anyone suggests it, let me add that we should not use setx.exe to naively modify `PATH`. setx.exe has to be carefully combined with reg.exe to modify the system or per-user "PATH" value in the registry. It's not trivial. For interactive editing, it's far simpler to use the GUI environment-variable editor.